# Rails application takes up all of the server memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memory-leaks, nginx, passenger

I am running a rails app (Passenger and nginx with mongodb and memcached) app on a ubuntu VPS (1GB RAM)- from a couple of days, I see that after starting nginx, ruby process slowly takes up all the memory of the box even though there are no requests on the server. new_relic shows the following 
[image]

top Output

```
top - 12:02:23 up  2:47,  1 user,  load average: 0.03, 0.02, 0.00
Tasks:  16 total,   1 running,  15 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,  1048576k used,        0k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

9993 mongodb   18   0  128m  29m  21m S    0  2.9   0:17.06 mongod                                                                                      
1135 nobody    18   0 71664  18m  856 S    0  1.8   0:00.55 memcached                              
14310 passenge  15   0  500m 434m 4660 S    0 42.5   0:13.59 ruby
15496 passenge  15   0  425m 360m 4648 S    0 35.3   0:13.06 ruby
```

I think there is some code leaking memory - or I need to somehow kill costly ruby processes on passenger whenever they reach some threshold. 
Please share some thoughts on both these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer, since there's not much info to go on so i'll answer this fairly generically.  A graph showing memory usage over time, or a graph showing degradation of response times would be helpful.

Anyway, i've got a similiar setup (Rails/Passenger/Nginx/MongoDB/VPS-1GB).

- First confirm your assumption of no requests by checking the logs to confirm there are no requests (and ensure logging is turned on enough in Nginx)
- Try disabling New Relic (as this heartbeats to their servers over time) and also review any other monitoring software you have (eg. Nagios).
- Try a free load-testing app (eg. http://loadimpact.com) and watch you memory/GC and processor graphs when it is being actively load tested.  If you see memory usage creeping up and up beyond a healthy amount, you can bet you have a memory leak somewhere.

If you find you do, it's really just a matter of eliminating variables - i'd suspend Rails over Nginx, but you could run Rails without a front-end, or turn off passenger and just hit all the static assets in Nginx to try and find the cause.

Hope this helps.